# Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ and $f:A \to \Bbb R$. Show that if $A = \bigcup_{i} B_i$ and $f\mid_{B_{i}}$ is measurable for any $i$ then $f$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ and $f:A \to \Bbb R$. Show that if $A = \bigcup_{i} B_i$ for $B_1, B_2, \dots$  and $f\mid_{B_{i}}$ is measruable for all $i$, then $f$ is measurable.

Since $f\mid_{B_{i}}$ is measurable for all $i$ we have that $E=\{x \in A \mid f\mid_{B_{i}}(x) > a \}$ is measurable for any $i$. Now since this holds for any $i$ $$E= \{x \in A \mid f\mid_{B_{i}}(x) > a \} = \{x \in A \mid f\mid_{\bigcup_i B_{i}}(x) > a \} = \{x \in A \mid f(x) > a \}$$ and so $f$ is measurable. Is the solution here correct?

Comment: I think you can use countable (sub) additivity here, or pull the union out, as a countable union of measurable is still measurable cause your $f(A)$ is really $f(\bigcup_i B_i)=\bigcup_i f(B_i)$

Comment: How $\{x \in A \mid f|_{B_{i}}(x) > a \} = \{x \in A \mid f|_{\bigcup_i B_{i}}(x) > a \}$ is true? If $B \subseteq \mathbb R$ is a Borel set, then $f^{-1}(B) = f^{-1}(B) \cap A = f^{-1}(B) \cap \bigcup_i B_i = \bigcup_i (f^{-1}(B) \cap B_i) = \bigcup_i (f|_{B_i})^{-1}(B)$. What can you conclude from here?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a measurable set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Then consider that

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f^{-1}(S) &= f^{-1}(S) \cap A \\
&= f^{-1}(S) \cap \bigcup\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} B_i \\
&= \bigcup\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} f^{-1}(S) \cap B_i \\
&= \bigcup\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} f|_{B_i}^{-1}(S)
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

which is a countable union of measurable sets, hence measurable. So $f$ is measurable.

Note that the fact that $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is not used here at all, nor is the fact that the codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$. Any measure spaces could have been used instead.

The key facts which are needed are that intersections distribute over arbitrary unions and that if $X \subseteq Y$, $g : Y \to Z$, $W \subseteq Z$, then $g^{-1}(W) \cap X = g|_X^{-1}(W)$.

Comment: that key fact though! nice!!